# Putting JSON data from Google sheets into an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, google-sheets

My sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1pruXYXrbITR7CoQXZG1I1kyS4DahYBXmGMDEK2T6MpY/edit?usp=sharing

I'm using Google sheets JSON data to display on my website but I want to put some of the data into arrays so it doesn't repeat itself on the website.

For example, this is how it displays, but I would like to be able to just have the one heading for each group (zouk, zen ect) and then all the members to be under the one header. 
https://www.kentunion.co.uk/test1/

So I am trying to figure out some javascript that adds all the positions of one group into an array. Go from this:

```
"Zouk Society" : {
      "name" : "Zouk Society",
      "position" : "President",
      "member" : "Currently Vacant"
    },
    "Zouk Society" : {
      "name" : "Zouk Society",
      "position" : "Secretary",
      "member" : "Currently Vacant"
    },
    "Zouk Society" : {
      "name" : "Zouk Society",
      "position" : "Treasurer",
      "member" : "Currently Vacant"
    }
```

to this:

```
"Zouk Society" [{
      "position" : "President",
      "member" : "Currently Vacant"
    },
    {
      "position" : "Secretary",
      "member" : "Currently Vacant"
    },
    {
      "position" : "Treasurer",
      "member" : "Currently Vacant"
    }
]
```

I have tried the following JS but I am just getting an error from it:

```
 // ID of the Google Spreadsheet
 var spreadsheetID = "1pruXYXrbITR7CoQXZG1I1kyS4DahYBXmGMDEK2T6MpY";

 // Make sure it is public or set to Anyone with link can view 
 var url = "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/1pruXYXrbITR7CoQXZG1I1kyS4DahYBXmGMDEK2T6MpY/od6/public/values?alt=json";
     $(document).ready(function () {
         $.getJSON(url, function(data) {

             var entry = data.feed.entry;

             $(entry).each(function(){
                  // Column names are name, age, etc.
                  $('.results').prepend('<h2>'+this.gsx$name.$t+'</h2><p>'+this.gsx$position.$t+'</p><p>'+this.gsx$member.$t+'</p>');
             });
         });

    var grouped = {};

        entry.forEach(function (a) {
          grouped[a.name] = grouped[a.name] || [];
                grouped[a.name].push({ position: a.position, member: a.member });
        });
        document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(grouped, 0, 4) + '</pre>');

  });
```

This is the error that I get:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: entry is not defined at
>   HTMLDocument. (scripts.js:19)

Comment: Can you post the error that you get?

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: entry is not defined
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (scripts.js:19)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't access entry outside of the callback scope.

Do your grouping inside the callback, like this:

```
// ID of the Google Spreadsheet
var spreadsheetID = "1pruXYXrbITR7CoQXZG1I1kyS4DahYBXmGMDEK2T6MpY";

// Make sure it is public or set to Anyone with link can view
var url = "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/1pruXYXrbITR7CoQXZG1I1kyS4DahYBXmGMDEK2T6MpY/od6/public/values?alt=json";

$(document).ready(function () {
    $.getJSON(url, function(data) {
        var entry = data.feed.entry;

        $(entry).each(function(){
            // Column names are name, age, etc.
            $('.results').prepend('<h2>'+this.gsx$name.$t+'</h2><p>'+this.gsx$position.$t+'</p><p>'+this.gsx$member.$t+'</p>');
        });

        var grouped = {};

        entry.forEach(function (a) {
            grouped[a.gsx$name.$t] = grouped[a.gsx$name.$t] || [];
            grouped[a.gsx$name.$t].push({ position: a.gsx$position.$t, member: a.gsx$member.$t });
        });

        document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(grouped, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
    });
});
```

Comment: this produces these results on my page: {
    "undefined": [
        {},
        {},
        {},
        {},
        {},
        {},
        {},
        {},
        {},
        {} ect

Comment: Ok, I see. I made a change, look at the edit. Is that what you expected?

Comment: Happy to help :)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot `push` data into object. You should change `var grouped = {}` into `var grouped = []`. Then you can push each element to this array of objects and access them with this syntax `grouped[0].position`.

I don't understand your spesific problem but "array of object" is the solution for your problem.

Comment: He/she tries to push into the array at grouped[a.name], not to grouped.
The array is initialized okay (grouped[a.name] = grouped[a.name] || [];).